# Setting size property in UIScrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I would like to create a scrollview inside of another view. I put a UIScrollview element in IB and declared a UIScrollview in my view controller file that is associated with the main view. I also declared it a property in the view controller header file and synthesized in the corresponding implementation file.

Do I set the size of the scrollview in the app delegate or in the view controller? If I set it in view controller do I still have to do the allocation and initialization commands for that instance? Or do I rely on the getter and setter methods that exist as a result of the scrollview being a property?

I should add that I only want the scrollview to occupy a part of the main view.

Here's my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 768, 1000)];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 1000)];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

The actual size of the UIScrollview in IB is 768 by 804, there should be a vertical scrollbar present (some of the UI elements in the scrollview are clipped, so there should definitely be a scrollbar if this view is set up correctly.)

Comment: there is some syntax error you are doing. that's when you get `expected identifier error`. recheck code.  it should be `[scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 768, 1000)];`

Comment: My entire `viewDidLoad` method is above, is there something else I am forgetting?

Comment: The view actually scrolls, I just didn't see a scrollbar when I ran the app.

Comment: cool, thats great. from here, i just did not see why your code didnt work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set the `frame` property of the `scrollView` instance using `setFrame`.

i.e. irrespective of what frame size you have defined in IB, using `[scrollView setFrame:CGFrameMake()];` you can redefine the exact width, height & x, y coordinates.

In fact this is how one goes about creating a dynamic view in iOS.

Once you are exiting this view entirely make sure you `dealloc` & `release` this IB instance since it would have been defines as `retain`.

Comment: Do I do this in the view controller file?

Comment: yes, you should do in your view controller file. So basically you are changing the dimensions of a UI element defined & created in IB but linked to a variable of the `UIScrollView` instance. clear?

Comment: oh and if I am using ARC, I don't need to do `dealloc` and `release`, right?

Comment: you could do it where ever you want the dimensions of your scrollview to change. anywhere actually. So to answer your question, yes you can do it in `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` or ...

Comment: See the addition to my question above, I am getting an error when I try to use `setFrame`

Comment: there is some syntax error you are doing. that's when you get `expected identifier error`. recheck code. it should be `[scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 768, 1000)];`

Comment: yep, I just corrected it, no error but I still see no scroll bar when I run the app.

Comment: there are other things that you might be missing. maybe u forgot to set `contentSize` ?